# Ruby automatically calls to_s method when object is created

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

```
class A
  def initialize(string, number)
    @string = string
    @number = number
  end

  def to_s
    "In to_s:\n   #{@string}, #{@number}\n"
  end
  def to_a
    "In to_a:\n   #{@string}, #{@number}\n"
  end
end
puts a = A.new("hello world", 5)
```

output is

```
 In to_s:
   hello world, 5
```

How is the `to_s` method called automatically?

Why isn't another method called automatically such as `to_a`?

Since I did not write puts in the `to_s` method, why is output printed.

Comment: Note that printing the new object, not creating it, is what triggers the call to `to_s`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're sending it to `puts`, which will try to render the object as a string using `to_s`.

If you changed your last line to: `puts A.new("hello world", 5).to_a`, it would instead call `to_s` on the returned Array and A's `to_s` would not be called.

Answer (score 1):

`puts` generally prints the result of applying `to_s` on an object
**read more**
[here](http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/45-more-classes/lessons/108-displaying-objects)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @numbers1311407 answer

whenever you try any code in `irb`

it calls `to_s` implicitly.

and as  @numbers1311407 answer explains.

puts call `to_s` implicitly

Comment: Close - it calls `inspect` implicitly, which then calls `to_s`.